# Play and Stop Audio with 2 seprate button Unity

Tags: c#, android, audio, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am trying to use 2 quads as buttons and one Script for playing an stopping an audio file. I have searched internet and I have not found a single solution for my problem.

this is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayStop : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Button1;
    public GameObject Button2;
    public AudioClip Clip;

    void Start()
    {
        Button1 = GameObject.Find ("Fa1Play");
        Button2 = GameObject.Find ("Fa1Stop");
    }
    void OnMouseDown ()
    {
        if (Button1.GetComponent ("Fa1Play"))
        {
            if (!audio.isPlaying)
            {
                audio.clip = Clip;
                audio.Play();
            }
        }

        if (Button2.GetComponent("Fa1Stop"))
        {
            audio.Stop();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: I did try HARDLY :D so I dont get any actions. I want to play an audio by pressing a button and stopping it with another button or even with same button. I have a gameobject PlayStop with 2 child Fa1Play and Fa1Stop. I am a little confused :(

Comment: and I want to do these on mouse down event !

Comment: Did the onMouseDown event works ? and with one button (just to play for example) ? if both answer are yes, you can do `if (audio.isPlaying){audio.Stop()}else{audio.Play()}`. Sorry I m not an expert in android, but my first comment was to suggest you to edit your question and improve it (to help others to answer it :) )

Comment: your welcome, I have did something like this once with online streaming and with separate buttons and separate scripts and it did happen but now I am really suffering from lack of resources and help :( and thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Did you receive a satisfied answer to this problem?

Comment: not yet Rika. it is really hard to find a suitable answer when there are limited resources

Answer (score 0):

you dont need game object finds just give your buttons colliders and tag give your pause a pause tag and play a play tag

```
      public class PlayStop : MonoBehaviour {

            public AudioClip aclip;
            private bool stop;

             void Start()
                {
                   audio.clip=aclip;
                   stop=true;
                }


    void Update () 
     {
        if(Input.touches.Length == 1)
        {
        Touch touchedFinger = Input.touches[0];

        if(touchedFinger.phase==TouchPhase.Began){ 
         Ray aRay = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(touchedFinger.position);
          RaycastHit hit;
          if(Physics.Raycast(aRay.origin, aRay.direction, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
               {

                            if(hit.collider.tag=="stop" && !stop)
                                  {
                                          audio.Stop();
                                          stop=!stop
                                  }
                         if(hit.collider.tag=="play" && stop)
                                  {
                                          audio.Play();
                                          stop=!stop
                                  }

                        }
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I assigned the audio to script on gameobject and add a audio source to gameobject and changed the tags to lowercase and I have an audio listener on AR camera !

Comment: put a debug inside if(hit.collider.tag=="stop" && !stop) and see it gets called

Comment: put them(SCRIPT AND AUDIOSOURCE) in another gameobject that is not parent or child of anybody a separate gameobject

Comment: my pc got restarted, so sorry. I opened the unity and now I get this error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: and I have put (script and audio source) in another gameobject !

Comment: yes put it in a gameobject that these buttons arent children of so i suggesst a empty gameobject with no parents and childs

Comment: nothing happens ! even Debug.Log doesn't work properly !!! I mean nothing written in console log !!!

Comment: your camera must be set to main camera and you can use debug.drawray to see if the ray is made correctly

Comment: that is the point, I cant use main camera !! is there any other way to use gameobject like quads or cubes as buttons ? like onmousedown if cube1 clicked do this and if cube2 clicked do that ?

Comment: maincamera works with vuforia but just in case you can make a camera var and assign your camera to it and make a ray from it

Comment: put a debug.log under if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) see if it gets the input or not

Comment: i changed the script to touch script it is tested see how this goes

Comment: if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) to if (Input.touches (0)) ?

Comment: make all the changes its a new script

Comment: all the script is here just swap the old code with new one

Comment: in if(hit.collider.tag=="stop" && !stop) ?